# C debugger which can be controlled by a file

Tags: c, perl, debugging, gcc, gdb

As I have learnt that a Perl debugger can be controlled dynamically using the file .perldb in your home directory, I was wondering if there is a C debugger also which can be manipulated in the same way. So I could set breakpoints at a certain point and print some variables and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set breakpoints and print values in GDB via commands in `~/.gdbinit`, yes.

Comment: Hello can you please give an example and guide me to a link with some resources??? Thank you

Comment: Most commands can be used in gdb scripts (like .gdbinit). See http://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/index.html.